# JS - Push functions into an array and name them

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I'm trying to add functions into an array. These have to be named 'opdracht1' through to 'opdracht10'.
Though, I cannot figure out how to give it a name.

```js
var opdrachtArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    opdrachtArray.push(function() {func(i); });
}
```

It adds the functions but as I said earlier I cannot find out how to add a name.

Also, am I later just able to define the functions and call them when I need them?

Comment: Why do they have to be named?

Comment: Because I'm going to use each function as a seperate assignment for what i'm making. This allows me to edit them seperately and keep them apart.

Comment: That smells like an XY problem... But may want to use a key/value object, instead of an array.

Comment: The functions have names, opdrachtArray[0 .. 9].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each function to be assigned to a name, use dictionary, not array:

```js
    var opdrachtDict = {};
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        opdrachtDict["opdracht"+i]=func.bind(null,i);
    }
    function func(i){
        alert(i);
    }

    opdrachtDict["opdracht3"](); //ok, lets call it and see if you think its still a wrong answer ;)...
```

Comment: "Unexptected Token [" @ line 3

Comment: Remove the dot after opdrachtArray, and you're done :)

Comment: "These have to be named 'opdracht1' through to 'opdracht10'." But here, they are not so named, but rather held in a dictionary with that as the key.

Comment: This accepted solution also does not fix an important bug in the OP's code, which is that all ten functions will call `func` with the value 10.

Answer (score 1):

Name your functions by placing them on the `window` object:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    f = function() { func(i); }); // but see below
    window['opdracht' + i] = f
    opdrachtArray.push(f);
}
```

However you have a more basic problem. All your functions close over `i` and therefore `func` is always going to be called with the value of `i` after the loop finishes, in other words, 10. One solution is:

```
function make_func(i) {
    return function() {
        return func(i); 
    };
}
```

then

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    f = make_func(i);
    window['opdracht' + i] = f;
    opdrachtArray.push(f);
}
```

Or

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    (function(i) {
        var f = function() { func(i); };
        window['opdracht' + i] = f
        opdrachtArray.push(f);
    }(i));
}
```

or just use `func.bind(null, i)`, which does approximately the same thing.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    f = func.bind(null, i);
    window['opdracht' + i] = f;
    opdrachtArray.push(f);
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to give an error.
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @OriginDutch: Cannot reproduce that error and can't imagine where it would come from.

Comment: Much better after the edits; a [new/different] programmer can easily miss assignments in expressions. I'm still not sure if they OP needs the functions to be "named in window" though. This answer also does answer the "next" question the OP will have.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the name and function in an object and push each object to the array:

```
var opdrachtArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    var name = 'opdracht' + (i+1);
    opdrachtArray.push({name : name, callback : function() {func(i); }});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a function defined in the global scope just ends up being a property of `self`/`window` anyways. i.e.:

```
function mr_function(){return 5;}
self["mr_function"];
window["mr_function"];
```

Both (property of `self` / `window`) reference the function we defined.  I guess you could name your function that way if you're careful.  Or assign them to some other object's property if you'd rather not make them global.